# How does pagination works on Zoho CRM API?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, zoho

I am fetching data from the Zoho CRM API

```py
import requests
import json  
import pandas  

refresh_token="xxxx"  
client_id="xxxx"
client_secret="xxx"  

req1=requests.post("https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?refresh_token=" + refresh_token + "&client_id="+ client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&grant_type=refresh_token")
print(req1.status_code)  
data=req1.json()  
acc_token=data['access_token']  

headers= {'Authorization': 'Zoho-oauthtoken '+acc_token}
url="https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads"  
r= requests.get(url,headers=headers)  
print(r.status_code)  
print(r.json())
```

I'm getting the response but I'm able to get only 200 records. The JSON response has the following detail at the end

```
'info': {'per_page': 200, 'count': 200, 'page': 1, 'more_records': True}}.
```

Please help me out to get all the records

Answer (score 0):

According to zoho documentation you can provide the `page=` and `per_page=` URL parameters to choose which page you want to read, and how many results you need.

Here is the documentation for the endpoint you are calling:
https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v2/get-records.html

And the related parameters:

> **sort_order** (string, optional) To sort the list of records in either
> ascending or descending order. Possible values:asc - ascending order;
> desc - descending order
>
> **sort_by** (string, optional) Specify the API name of the field based on
> which the records must be sorted. Possible values: Field API names.
> Example: Email
>
> **page** (integer, optional) To get the list of records from the
> respective pages. Default value for page is 1. Possible values:
> Positive Integer values only.
>
> **per_page** (integer, optional) To get the list of records available per
> page. Default value for page is 200. Possible values: Positive Integer
> values only.

Calling `https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads?page=2` should give you the next 200 results

Comment: How to get all the records in the output. How to combine all pages and get the output @Eloims

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll use **`pagination`** for that you've to write code something like this.

```
more_records = True
page_number = 1

while more_records:
    get_url="https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads?page="+str(page_number)
    r = requests.get(url=get_url, headers=headers)

    for lead in r:
      """YOUR CODE"""

    page_number += 1
    more_records = r.json()['more_records']
```

Comment: I'm able to fetch 200 records and I'm getting KeyError: 'access_token'.

Comment: what does lead mean?

Comment: You'll get 200 records in one page then again hit same url with page=2 then other records will come then you will able to fetch them......while loop is for pagination till `more_records` is true and for loop is to fetch all coming record one by one....lead mean a single record in `r`